# How to position the footer at the end of the page?

Tags: footer

I know this is a repeated question but I'm very new to programming and only self-taught myself how to do it for a school project. Anyway, I'm stuck at positioning my footer at the bottom of my page, and I've seen so many solutions but I can't apply any to my already existing lines of code. Please help.

Here's my code:

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeIV3.png)

[css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcr6n.png)

Comment: Just place it at the end of your code container. Right after the body.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! please try to be more specific and show some search or some trials that you have made I recommend to read how to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
at least you have to post your code to allow community to help out!

Comment: hey thanks for the feedback, I posted my code as a link because stack overflow told me I'm not allowed to post an image yet.

Comment: Thank you guys for replying. I found a solution.